# How to make the object type dynamic

Tags: c#

I'm using the predicatebuilder, and depending on the user input, can call the predicate against one of 2 object types  or

Rather than:

```
var personPredicateBuilder = PredicateBuilder.False<Person>
var animalPredicateBuilder = PredicateBuilder.False<Animal>
```

Is there a way I can make the object type dynamic?

Ie,

```
MyObject = Animal,

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MyObject>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dynamic declaration.

```
dynamic e = GetEmployee();
```

You don't need to cast or declare type Employee. The runtime takes over and then searches and allow to navigate with the properties.

```
e.GetSalary();
```

For example.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that works in my example, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Then you can check the runtime type e.GetType() == typeof(Animal) or e.GetType() == typeof(Person)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, I end up still having to do an if statement to test what type it it

Comment: I need more context of the situation to give you a more elaborate answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [Generic in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

By using generic you can define your predicate like

```
PredicateBuilder.False<T>
```

and this `T can be Person/Animal`, simply whatever way you design

For more information on [Predicate`<T>` Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT 1**

T can be anything, in your scenario it can be a simple Class type or may be customized object with minimal set of property that your PredicateBuilder require

```
public class YourClass
{
   Public static <returnType> YourFunction<T>
   {
      //someAction
   }
}



  //YourObject can be anything Person/Animal
   var predicate = YourClass.YourFunction<YourObject>();
```

So you don't need to define T in this scenario

Although you can restrict T like

```
class MyClass<T, U>
    where T : class
    where U : struct
{ }
```

Comment: How do I declare T?

Answer (score -1):

Way to do it is using switch case or factory pattern.

Comment: This should be a comment